# Uncaught ReferenceError: personal is not defined

Tags: javascript

As I don't program in Javascript, I have no clue where to begin. A friend asked me to take a look at a website that went from working to not working, I've figured out it's the javascript and Google Chrome's Javascript is tossing a couple errors -- This is what I've put together:

```
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: personal is not definedpersonal-training.html:53 (anonymous function)
```

call:

```
<table align="left" border="0" width="750px" height="400px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:25px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
displayPersonal(personal);
</script>
</table>
```

The function:

```
var personal = {"TEXT":"TEXT", 
"TEXT":"TEXT", 
"TEXT":"TEXT"};
```

I hate to ask such an open-ended question, and I'm sure it'll be an easy answer, but I don't really know javascript.  Thanks in advance.

personal is from variables.js

and it is loaded in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fadeslideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/xxx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/variables.js"></script>
```

here is display personal -- sorry about that:

```
function displayPersonal(personal) {
var first = true;
for (i in personal) {
if (first) {
first = false;
document.write("<tr><td style=\"padding-bottom:2px;color:#cc9900;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;\">" + i + "</td></tr>");
} else {
document.write("<tr><td style=\"padding-bottom:2px;color:#cc9900;border-top:1px #FBD84E solid;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;\">" + i + "</td></tr>");
}
document.write("<tr><td style=\"padding-top:2px; text-align:justify;\">Includes:<br>");
document.write(personal[i] + "</td></tr>");
}
}
```

Also, everything is loaded in the head prior to the call. Thanks.

Comment: can you just post the full code, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: where is `personal` variable created?

Comment: I've heard the best way to get around those pesky JavaScript Syntax Errors is to know JavaScript.

Comment: @ArunPJohny in a file called variables.js here is the head: 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fadeslideshow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xxx.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/variables.js"></script>

Comment: @DanHeberden I'm not going to learn the syntax of a new language because a friend asks for help every four years. I figured this was an easy question -- or something -- that was just a matter of something silly happening. I always appreciate tips, though. Thanks.

Comment: @kristophergardham whether `personal` is in a function? also whether the `variables.js` is included before the `displayPersonal(personal);` script

Comment: sometimes it is not as easy as it seems...even if your javascript is loaded correct, there are other problems, like: maybe 'personal' is in a different scope...more info you help.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've added the function (sorry abotu that) and variables.js is loaded in the head. Chrome is spitting out another error..Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL which points to this... var personal = {"TEXT" : "If you\'re interested in a bigger training package please contact us for more information!"}; -- I don't know if it could be the \' -- I'm not sure how javascript escapes that stuff.  Those are the only two things chrome is telling me.

Comment: @kristophergardham try to scope the var "i" in 'for (i in personal) {' like 'for (var i in personal) {', if "i" is defined outside of the function, you can get a key that doesn't exists in personal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your javascript is loading in the right order (maybe it's the case):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var personal = {"TEXT":"TEXT", "TEXT":"TEXT", "TEXT":"TEXT"};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
displayPersonal(personal);
</script>
```

...or:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url/to/personal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
displayPersonal(personal);
</script>
```

Hope that helps.